# yolo v1: how gradients in grids with no objects overpower

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am reading yolo v1 paper. I am having confusion while trying to understand this:

"Also, in every image many grid cells do not contain any
object. This pushes the “confidence” scores of those cells
towards zero, often overpowering the gradient from cells
that do contain objects. This can lead to model instability,
causing training to diverge early on."

Are we looking at gradients of loss with respect to confidence here?
I am confused about how exactly a grid with no object would lead to higher gradients since we are interested in sum squared error and the goal is to minimize difference between predicted and actual confidence. So I think it shouldn't matter if confidence in a cell is zero.
Any elaboration in this regard would be much appreciated.